# NServiceBus - subscribing to events created by a non nservicebus publisher

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, nservicebus, azureservicebus

I'm creating an Azure worker role that will subscribe to some events published by a service that I don't have any control over. Both the publisher and subscriber will be hosted in Azure.

The role will be part of a cloud service that is already using NServiceBus to publish and subscribe to events that it owns. To be consistent, I'm looking to use the same libraries in the new role.

The publisher of the event is not using NServiceBus. They are using the WindowsAzure.ServiceBus package to create BrokeredMessage objects and JSON.Net to serialize the message payloads. They are also using a 'topic per event type' pattern.

There are 3 topics I need my role to subscribe to, ItemActivated, ItemDeactived and ItemExpired. Each topic has a single event type published to it, and the event definition is available to me through a shared nuget package. The events are ItemActivatedEventV1, ItemDeactivedEventV1 etc...

Using the event definitions I can write message handlers, but I'm not convinced NServiceBus is the correct choice in the subscriber. Since the publisher isn't using NServiceBus, none of the message headers will be present - will this impact the behaviour of the subscriber?

The 'topic per event' is also different to the NServiceBus 'endpoint' approach, where multiple events sent to a single endpoint. Is it possible to configure NServiceBus to listen to multiple topics, e.g using MessageHandlerMappings in app.config?

Finally, the subscriber can be configured using JsonSerializer, but this isn't going to be guaranteed to be exactly the same at both ends of the communication. Is this going to impact behaviour?

Has anyone had any experience with this scenario? Any advice appreciated

Comment: I would separate bare and NSB infrastructures and make a satellite that will receive messages in the standard Azure way and re-publish it inside NServiceBus.